# How can I find deleted notes (even in recycle bin) in Xiaomi?

Tags: data-recovery, xiaomi, notes

I deleted my Xiaomi notes in the cloud, but I saw my notes are deleted in the app too.

How can I find my notes? Maybe there are some folders. Should I root my phone to find them?

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145842/discussion-on-question-by-kaan-ayhanogullari-how-can-i-find-deleted-notes-even); please do not continue the discussion here.